# Change URL of Umbraco homePage

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco with my current website so two folders in IIS one for my current website and one for Umbraco as Umbraco homepage is serving blog in my website but the URL is mywebsite.com/homepage. How can I can I change URL to mywebsite.com/blog

I tried to change Name and Alias property under templates.
But it is not changing the URL.

Comment: If you made the name change in Umbraco but don't see the results through your browser, I wonder if it could be a case of an hard cache.  You could try deleting your /TEMP items from Umbraco, then recycling the associated app pool from IIS, and then restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me your iis application is bound to "mywebsite.com/homepage" instead of "mywebsite.com/blog". Can you check this? Also you can check the hostname that Umbraco is bound to (right mouse on rootnode and select Hostnames).

Comment: how to do for root node e.g. Homepage? In my case homepage=blog other pages are aboutme and projects which are under homepage.

Comment: I've updated my answer after reading the question again, hope this helps

Comment: i checked my IIS -  in advance setting PhysicalPath  is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Umbracofolder and I checked hostname - no domain is attached -  Language is inherit and Domains section only have Add new domain button.